# Caching images in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4, image-caching

I am working on ionic 4 app which includes swiping of images to left or right. Currently the images are fetched from the server every time which causes a delay in image loading. Could any one suggest an efficient way to cache or preload the images so as to increase the performance of the app by loading images from cache.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img

If you can lazy load the images.

Comment: See this:https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/tree/v4

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use [`ionic-img-cache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-cache)  and it works with Ionic Framework (v >= 1.0)  or ['ionic-cli'](https://medium.com/ninjadevs/caching-images-ionic-ccf2f4ca8d1f)   and see [this](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/tree/v4) also.
All links have an example. Run the first example [here](https://npm.runkit.com/ionic-img-cache) and another option is using [`LoadingController`](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-ion-loading-web-component-in-ionic-4-angular-application/#more-2198)

Answer (score 1):

use [ion-media-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-media-cache) this directive is to store image in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin it has the feature of caching image.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader

Comment: used this but this is not working as expected in ionic 4, in ionic 3 it works fine.

Comment: for ionic v4 use this plugin
https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/tree/v4

Answer (score -3):

You Just use the tag   it help to lazy load image attribute  it's help t